# WebHeaderCollection convenience initializer F#

Tags: .net, f#

Is there are nice way to initialize a WebHeaderCollection in F# like I do here in C#?

```
var wh = new WebHeaderCollection
{
    { "Content-Type", "application/json" }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C# code corresponds to the following F#, which actually does not look too bad if you just need it inside a method when initializing the collection:

```
let wh = WebHeaderCollection()
wh.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
```

You could define various helpers to make this easier. If you wanted a fancy one, you could define a helper that takes the class name and a list of items to add and invokes the `Add` method via a static member constraint (which also is pretty much what the C# compiler does):

```
let inline create ctor list : ^T = 
  let res = ctor()
  for k, v in list do
    (^T : (member Add : ^K * ^V -> unit) (res, k, v)) 
  res
```

With this helper, you can initialize the collection as follows:

```
let wh = create WebHeaderCollection ["Content-Type", "application/json"]
```

That said, I would probably just call the `Add` method directly unless you have a good reason not to.

If you have some more complicated structure that you need to initialize, then it might be better to think about the problem differently and define a couple of F# discriminated unions and records to model your domain in a nice idiomatic F# way rather than creating the .NET objects directly. Then, you'd write a function to turn your F# domain into .NET objects, but this would just be one transformation (and you could use your nice F# domain to do most of the work).